# write a java method insertNodeBefore which takes two integers int a and int b

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Two given classes:

```
public class Node { 
    int  data;  
    Node next;  

    Node(int d, Node n){   
        data = d;   
        next = n;       
    } 
}  

public class List{  
    Node header;
}
```

write a java method insertNodeBefore which takes two integers int a( which is the data of the new node we want to insert) and int b(which is the data of the node that we need to insert a new node before) for the list mylist...

Following is what i have and i am not sure about it:

```
public void insertNodeBefore(int a, int b) {
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode();
    newNode.data = b;
    header.next = newNode;
    header.next.next = newNode.next;
}
```

Comment: Kindly do your own homework. If you have a *specific* problem or are stuck with some specific issue, feel free to post here, but don't just dump your homework.

Comment: I have edited the code i have so far...please check it

Comment: Writing code is just the first step. You want to think about ways how you can **test** what you did. Like: write code that creates lists. Inserts data. Prints lists. And so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert method as like something below, do some tests

```
public void insert(Node head,int a,int before){
    Node prev = null;
    while(head!=null){
        // Matched at head;
        if(prev==null && head.a==before){
            Node fresh = new Node(a);
            fresh.next=head;
            head=fresh;
            break;
        } else if(head.a==before){
            Node fresh = new Node(a);
            fresh.next=head;
            prev.next = fresh;
            break;
        }
        prev = head.next;
        head = head.next;

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh great, you did all the work for him. Dont expect many upvotes for that.